# How to make toggle on which define in listview adapter from activity in android?

Tags: android, listview, android-adapter, switchcompat

I have an app which contain listview with switch compat which define in listview adapter. What i want to enable/disable switch a method in activity which contain listview. How do i do that.

code of adapter:-

```
listViewHolder.switchCompat.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(final CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            if (isChecked) {
                new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext, R.style.AppCompatAlertDialogStyle).setTitle("Warning").setMessage("You want to whiteList this application?").setPositiveButton("YES", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                        //retrieve data from shared preference
                        String jsonScore = sharedPreference.getAppsArrayListData();
                        Type type = new TypeToken<ArrayList<WhiteListModel>>() {
                        }.getType();
                        existingDataSet = gson.fromJson(jsonScore, type);

                        //Adding items in Dataset
                        AllAppList appList = listStorage.get(position);
                        whiteListModel.setName(appList.getName());
                        whiteListModel.setPackName(appList.getPackName());


                        if (existingDataSet != null) {
                            existingDataSet.add(whiteListModel);
                            saveScoreListToSharedpreference(existingDataSet);
                        } else {
                            newDataSet.add(whiteListModel);
                            saveScoreListToSharedpreference(newDataSet);
                        }

                        //Notifying adapter data has been changed.....
                        notifyDataSetChanged();
                        listViewHolder.switchCompat.setChecked(false);


                    }
                }).setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        listViewHolder.switchCompat.setChecked(false);
                    }
                }).show();

            }

        }
    });
```

code of listview click:-

```
private List<AllAppList> getInstalledApps() {
    List<AllAppList> res = new ArrayList<AllAppList>();
    List<PackageInfo> packs = getPackageManager().getInstalledPackages(0);
    for (int i = 0; i < packs.size(); i++) {
        PackageInfo p = packs.get(i);
        if ((!isSystemPackage(p))) {
            if (p.applicationInfo.packageName.equalsIgnoreCase("com.soopermo.batterybooster")){
                continue;
            }
            boolean isWhiteList = false;
            if (whiteListModels != null) {
                for (int j = 0; j < whiteListModels.size(); j++) {
                    model = whiteListModels.get(j);
                    Log.e(TAG, "p*****" + model.getPackName());
                    if (p.applicationInfo.packageName.equalsIgnoreCase(model.getPackName())) {
                        // This package is whitlist package
                        isWhiteList = true;
                        //Here is want to enable/disable switch

                    }
                }
            }
```

Comment: What i understood from your question is: you have a listView which is having itemView as a textView and a switch, on change of switch in your list view you want to reflect that change in your activity. i.e you change something in your item in adapter it should notify that change to activity on to which that adapter is attached..Is that so??

Comment: No I want to change switch state from a method that is in an activity .

Comment: swicth is in Adapter class

Comment: YOu can do it via a bean or model class. simply change your attributes in bean and update your adapter according to it

Comment: pls refer some code snipshots

Answer (score 1):

Do it via a model class.

**Item.java**

```
public class Item{
    private String appName;
    private boolean isEnable;
    public String getAppName(){
        return this.appName;
    }
    public void setAppName(String name){
        this.appName = name;
    }
    public boolean isEnabled(){
        return this.isEnabled;
    } 
    public void setEnabled(boolean value){
        this.isEnabled = value;
    }
}
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
List<Item> myItems = new ArrayList<>();
...
..onCreate(Bundle savedInstance){
 ...//your code
YourAdapter adapter = new YourAdapter(MainActivity.this, myItems);//pass the list of items.
yourListView.setAdapter(adapter);

//your action call when you want to trigger the change suppose 2nd item has to be enabled.
myItems.get(1).setEnabled(true);

//and after that notify this change to your adapter
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

}
```

**YourAdapter.java**

```
List<Items> itemList;
Context context;

public YourAdapter(Context context, List<Items> itemList){
    this.context = context;
    this. itemList = itemList;
}

public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){
    ...//you code to inflate your view
    Items item = itemList.get(position);

    if(item.isEnabled()){
        //toggle your switch.
    }

}
```

my Item.java is same as your AllApplist.java, simply put a boolean in it and do it as it is done in the code..